# XSLT 1.0 How to truncate or trim the decimal value

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a filed which is amount and it is like 123.589922..

But I want only two digits after the dot . For example: `123.58`

Please suggest any XSLT function to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried already? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Try format-number function for that

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.00')"/>
```

Comment: This will round off the decimal part at second place. Is there a way, we only trim the value? I need a solution to trim after 7th decimal place without rounding. Thanks.

Comment: @Nik, you can use `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor(. * 10000000) div 10000000, '#.0000000')"/>` for your condition.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get two decimal points with XSLT-1.0 is using a `substring` combination:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(text(),'.'),'.', substring(substring-after(text(),'.'),1,2))" />
```

Its output is:

> 123.58